# SQL Order By Case Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have Created an SQL statement that should return a List of Items that is Sorted by the Relevance to Three words that are Provided. (TAG_1, TAG_2 etc). Here is the Code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SEARCH_POSTS WHERE(
    POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%'
    OR POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%'
) ORDER BY(
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END CASE + 
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
    END CASE +    
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END CASE +
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END CASE +     
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
    END CASE +    
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END CASE +
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END CASE +     
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
    END CASE +    
    CASE 
    WHEN  POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END CASE) DESC");
```

The WHERE clause is Working fine, but its Seems that the ORDER BY(...) is giving me an Error. What am I doing wrong? Everything looks to be In order. Thank you.

Comment: That's what I get for Copy Pasting my Code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`END CASE` should just be `END`. `END CASE` is used to end `CASE` statements in stored procedures, it's not used to end `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the Issue. I should stop copy Pasting segments of Code. Doesn't really save time in the End.

Answer (score 0):

you are using unwanted `case`. Try this `order by`

```
ORDER  BY( CASE WHEN POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_1 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_2 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_1']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_2']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN POST_TAG_3 LIKE '%{$_POST['TAG_3']}%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) DESC
```